# Basic Bash script results in "edge.sh: line 13: npm: command not found" found issue here but it didn't resolve

Tags: windows, bash, command, git-bash

The following simple script is apparently not so simple.
The entire script appears to work properly until I get to the npm command.
I have looked at the numerous threads here, but none of the solutions fix the issue.

Each of the scripts is kicked off by a parent script. 
Here is the parent:

```
#!/bin/bash/

authGogglesPath='/c/sandBox/amazon-sandbox/CraigMonroe/platform.shared.auth-goggles'

echo $'\nExecuting node commands for local running solution...\n'
#echo $(pwd)

# run the scripts
bash edge.sh ${edgePath} &

exec bash
```

- I checked my path in the terminal and it's aware
- I thought that it might be running as another associated profile so I tried the full path to npm, but the same results.

```
#!/bin/bash/

authGogglesPath='/c/sandBox/amazon-sandbox/CraigMonroe/platform.shared.auth-goggles'

echo $'\nExecuting node commands for local running solution...\n'
#echo $(pwd)

# run the scripts
bash edge.sh ${edgePath} &

exec bash
```

---

That calls edge.sh with a string path for arg (more for later)

edge.sh is another simple script

```
#!/bin/bash/

PATH=$1
#echo $PATH

if [ -z "${PATH}" ] ; then
    "PATH is empty! Aborting"
    exit 1
fi
cd "${PATH}"

echo $'\nExecuting Edge...\n'
npm run dev
```

Each time I run this I'm receiving:

```
$ bash edge.sh /c/sandBox/amazon-sandbox/CraigMonroe/platform.shared.auth-goggles/

Executing Edge...

edge.sh: line 13: npm: command not found

cmonroe@LP10-G6QD2X2 MINGW64 ~/cruxScripts
$
```

When in the terminal and manually navigating to the directory and running the command it works properly. Where the edge builds and starts.

Comment: typically you "enhance" your PATH variable (inside of a script), like `PATH="/new/dir:$PATH"`. **Then** you don't wipe out the other dirs that where originally in your `PATH` var. When the script ends, your std PATH is restored (that is a feature ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Unless npm is in `/c/sandBox/amazon-sandbox/CraigMonroe/platform.shared.auth-goggles/`, doing `PATH=$1` means your `PATH` only refers to that one folder.
No more `/usr/bin` or any other folders your bash session might need.

As commented, *adding* to the PATH should work

```
PATH="$1:${PATH}"
```